# Пунктуация в альтернативном вопросе

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, двоеточие

*Ты какое вино предпочитаешь — красное или белое?*

В данном предложении какой знак должен быть? Двоеточие, тире, запятая?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Запятая в таком предложении "не смотрится", я бы поставил тире. *Красное* и *белое* — уточняющие члены предложения.

[**Двоеточие — тире**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189) (Розенталь)

> 6. Параллельное употребление двоеточия и тире встречается при обособлении **пояснительных** и **уточняющих** членов предложения: *Как долго продолжалось это молчание (: —) минуту, три, десять?*; *Сколько мне тогда было (: —) девятнадцать или двадцать?*; *Не знаю, когда уехать (: —) в среду или в четверг.*
>
> В заключение можно указать, что в «конкурентной борьбе» двоеточия с тире «победителем» нередко выходит тире. Это явление отмечается многими исследователями, которые считают, что «в целом тире — знак более свободный, заходящий и во владения двоеточия» и что «выявляется тенденция к вытеснению в ряде случаев двоеточия знаком тире».