# Двоеточие или тире? Какое правило?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире, однородные-члены, двоеточие

> Кого ты боишься() меня или маму?

Какой знак поставить на месте пропуска? Попрошу, если вам не сложно, ссылку на правило. Заранее спасибо)

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/460179/192807